# Matrix inverse in FreeMat and in NumPy gives different outputs

Tags: numpy, freemat

I am utterly confused. I tried the following in [FreeMat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeMat):

```
Y1 = [0.1637 -  0.4288i,  -0.0460 +  0.1117i,  -0.1165 +  0.2828i,        0;
  -0.0460 +  0.1117i,   0.1090 -  0.3526i,  -0.0583 +  0.1414i,        0;
  -0.1165 +  0.2828i,  -0.0583 +  0.1414i,   0.5422 -  1.0004i,  -0.3663 +  0.5495i;
        0,                  0,            -0.3663 +  0.5495i,   0.3663 -  0.5495i]

Z1 = inv(Y1)
```

The output is:

```
Z1 =
0.9263 +  7.9980i  -0.0021 +  5.4516i   0.4569 +  6.7866i   0.4569 +  6.7866i
-0.0021 +  5.4516i   0.4434 +  6.6566i   0.0342 +  5.5501i   0.0342 +  5.5501i
0.4569 +  6.7866i   0.0342 +  5.5501i   0.9363 +  7.9718i   0.9363 +  7.9718i
0.4569 +  6.7866i   0.0342 +  5.5501i   0.9363 +  7.9718i   1.7763 +  9.2318i
```

I tried the same thing in [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy):

```
Y1 = np.matrix(  ((0.1637 -  0.4288j,  -0.0460 +  0.1117j,  -0.1165 +  0.2828j,        0),
  (-0.0460 +  0.1117j,   0.1090 -  0.3526j,  -0.0583 +  0.1414j,        0),
  (-0.1165 +  0.2828j,  -0.0583 +  0.1414j,   0.5422 -  1.0004j,  -0.3663 +  0.5495j),
  (      0,                  0,            -0.3663 +  0.5495j,   0.3663 -  0.5495j)) )
print np.linalg.inv(Y1)
```

The output is:

```
[[ 0.86953959+6.88397793j  0.00715465+4.54141578j  0.32473444+5.47695118j
   0.32473444+5.47695118j]
 [ 0.00715465+4.54141578j  0.49628324+5.91573859j -0.00822597+4.47684505j
  -0.00822597+4.47684505j]
 [ 0.32473444+5.47695118j -0.00822597+4.47684505j  0.70375023+6.43596174j
   0.70375023+6.43596174j]
 [ 0.32473444+5.47695118j -0.00822597+4.47684505j  0.70375023+6.43596174j
   1.54375023+7.69596174j]]
```

Why are the outputs different?

On second thoughts, it seems to me that the problem might be elsewhere in the source code, so here is the Python routine:

```
#ROEPER SHORT CIRCUIT CALCULATION EXAMPLE
import numpy as np

#Constants
a = np.exp(2*np.pi/3);
A = np.matrix( ((1., 1., 1.), (1., a**2., a), (1., a, a**2.)), dtype=np.complex64)

#System description at Bus 1
S_NG1 = 100. #generator rated apparent power in MVA 
U_NG1 = 10.5 #generator rated voltage in kV
xst_dG1 = 10.5 #relative initial subtransient reactance in percent
r_G1 = 0.3 #generator resistance in percent
S_NT1 = 100. # transformer rated capacity in MVA
U_NT1LV = 10.5 #in kV
U_NT1HV = 115. #in kV
u_kNT1 = 11.5 #in percent
u_RNT1 = 0.5 #in percent
n_ZT1 = 0.8 #ratio of zero to positive sequence impedance 
#Sequence impedance calculations -----------------------
Z1_G1 = complex(r_G1, xst_dG1)*(1./100.)*((U_NG1**2)/S_NG1)*(U_NT1HV/U_NT1LV)**2
#print Z1_G1
Z2_G1 = Z1_G1
Z1_T1 = complex(u_RNT1/100., u_kNT1/100.)*((U_NT1HV**2)/S_NT1)
#print Z1_T1
Z2_T1 = Z1_T1
Z0_T1 = n_ZT1*Z1_T1

#System description at Bus 2
S_NT2 = 200. # transformer rated capacity in MVA
U_NT2LV = 115. #transformer LV side nominal voltage in kV
U_NT2HV = 230. #in kV
u_kNT2 = 12. #in percent
u_RNT2 = 0.3 #in percent
n_ZT2 = 2.4 #ratio of zero to positive sequence impedance
#Sequence impedance calculations ------------------
Z1_T2 = complex(u_RNT2/100, u_kNT2/100.)*((U_NT2LV**2)/S_NT2)
#print Z1_T2
Z2_T2 = Z1_T2
Z0_T2 = n_ZT2*Z1_T2

#System description at Bus 3
S_NG3 = 75. #generator rated apparent power in MVA 
U_NG3 = 10.5 #generator rated voltage in kV
xst_dG3 = 11.2 #relative initial subtransient reactance in percent
r_G3 = 0.3 #generator resistance in percent
S_NT3 = 75. # transformer rated capacity in MVA
U_NT3LV = 10.5 #in kV
U_NT3HV = 115. #in kV
u_kNT3 = 10. #in percent
u_RNT3 = 0.6 #in percent
n_ZT3 = 0.8 
Sst_kQ = 12000. #initial a.c. short circuit power at 2Q in MVA
U_NQ = 230. #rated voltage of the system at point of connection 2Q in kV
U_Q = 220.
U_N2 = 115.
RX_Q = 0.1 
#Sequence impedance calculations ------------------
Z1_G3 = complex(r_G3, xst_dG3)*(1/100)*((U_NG3**2)/S_NG3)*(U_NT3HV/U_NT3LV)**2
Z2_G3 = Z1_G3
Z1_T3 = complex(u_RNT3/100, u_kNT3/100)*((U_NT3HV**2)/S_NT3)
Z2_T3 = Z1_T3
Z0_T3 = n_ZT3*Z1_T3
Z1Q = complex(0.1, 1.0)*1.1*((U_Q**2)/Sst_kQ)*(U_N2/U_NQ)**2
Z2Q = Z1Q

#Bus interconnections
Z1_12 = complex(3.154, 7.657) #in ohms
Z2_12 = Z1_12 #in ohms
Z0_12 = complex(10.431, 31.673) #in ohms
G0_12 = complex(0, 1./(1.056*(10.**4.))) #in mhos

Z1_23 = complex(2.490, 6.045) #in ohms
Z2_23 = Z1_23 #in ohms
Z0_23 = complex(8.235, 25.005) #in ohms
G0_23 = complex(0, 1./(1.337*(10.**4.))) #in mhos

Z1_13 = complex(1.245, 3.023) #in ohms
Z2_13 = Z1_13 #in ohms
Z0_13 = complex(4.118, 12.503) #in ohms
G0_13 = complex(0, 1./(2.674*(10.**4.))) #in mhos

Z1_2Q = complex(0.173, 0.980) #in ohms
Z2_2Q = Z1_2Q

Z1_34 = complex(0.840, 1.260) #in ohms
Z2_34 = Z1_34
Z0_34 = complex(5.440, 3.430)
G0_34 = complex(0, 1./(1.098*(10.**3.))) #in mhos

#Creation of Y matrix for positive & negative sequence components
y1_11 = 1/(Z1_G1+Z1_T1)+1/Z1_12+1/Z1_13;
y1_12 = -1/Z1_12;
y1_13 = -1/Z1_13;
y1_14 = 0+0j;
y1_21 = y1_12;
y1_22 = 1/(Z1_T2+Z1_2Q+Z1Q)+1/Z1_12+1/Z1_23;
y1_23 = -1/Z1_23;
y1_24 = 0+0j;
y1_31 = y1_13;
y1_32 = y1_23;
y1_33 = 1/(Z1_G3+Z1_T3)+1/Z1_13+1/Z1_23+1/Z1_34;
y1_34 = -1/Z1_34;
y1_41 = 0+0j;
y1_42 = 0+0j;
y1_43 = y1_34;
y1_44 = 1/Z1_34;


Y1 = np.matrix( ((y1_11, y1_12, y1_13, y1_14),
      (y1_21, y1_22, y1_23, y1_24),
      (y1_31, y1_32, y1_33, y1_34),
      (y1_41, y1_42, y1_43, y1_44)) )

Z1 = np.linalg.inv(Y1);
Ist_k3 = 1.1*110./(np.sqrt(3)*Z1[3,3])
If3ph = abs(Ist_k3)
print If3ph
phi_3ph = np.angle(Ist_k3, deg=True)
print phi_3ph
```

Comment: What happens if you multiply the inverse by the original matrix? Does it come out to the identity in both cases? If one of the computations is flat-out wrong, that will identify it. And if they both do (somehow) work out to be the identity, what happens if you take the inverse from Freemat, import it to Numpy, and multiply by the original matrix there? Or vice versa?

Comment: freemat output of Y1*Z1 is:  `1.0000 +  0.0000i   0.0000 +  0.0000i   0.0000 +  0.0000i   0.0000 +  0.0000i
  -0.0000 +  0.0000i   1.0000 +  0.0000i  -0.0000 -  0.0000i  -0.0000 +  0.0000i
  -0.0000 -  0.0000i  -0.0000 -  0.0000i   1.0000 -  0.0000i  -0.0000 +  0.0000i
   0.0000 +  0.0000i   0.0000 +  0.0000i   0.0000 +  0.0000i   1.0000 +  0.0000i`

Comment: numpy output of Y1*Z1 is:  `[[  1.00000000e+00 +2.22044605e-16j   2.22044605e-16 +2.22044605e-16j
    2.22044605e-16 +2.22044605e-16j   2.22044605e-16 +2.22044605e-16j]
 [ -1.11022302e-16 +0.00000000e+00j   1.00000000e+00 +5.55111512e-17j
   -1.11022302e-16 -5.55111512e-17j  -1.11022302e-16 -5.55111512e-17j]
 [  0.00000000e+00 +6.66133815e-16j   4.44089210e-16 +4.44089210e-16j
    1.00000000e+00 +6.66133815e-16j   8.88178420e-16 +6.66133815e-16j]
 [  0.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j   0.00000000e+00 -2.22044605e-16j
   -4.44089210e-16 +0.00000000e+00j   1.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j]]`

Comment: Weird. I guess if the matrix is nearly singular then it sort of makes sense that there would be sizable numerical errors. In any case it seems that freemat does better here...

Comment: @David - freemat is just displaying the result with less precision.  `Y1*Z1` effectively yields an identity matrix in both cases.

Comment: @Joe: ah, okay, I've never used freemat so I guess I just assumed it would show any small nonzero imaginary component as numpy does.

Answer (score 0):

Some matrices are unstable to numerical operations, like your matrix `Y1`. The numerical behavior of matrices is characterized by its [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number). Condition numbers close to 1 are fine, `cond(Y1)` gives 45.

See for instance *[numpy.linalg.cond](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cond.html)*.